# Setting a string of ASCII-art to a variable while escaping special characters

Tags: ruby

I'm working in Ruby and I'd like to set a huge string of ASCII-art characters to a variable, however I am running into some problems dealing with special characters.  Most ASCII-art contains octothorps and quotes and all sorts of problematic special characters that require escaping.  Is there any easy way to escape mass bulks of special characters without having to go into each and every single character one by one?

Comment: You should probably ask this question tagged with your editor, not with Ruby. If you get your string into Ruby, your problem is already solved. The easiest way to deal with it in Ruby itself is to load it from a file - they wouldn't need escaping that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use heredoc. That is what it is for. With heredoc, you can set the terminating string to any string that does not appear in your ASCII art. Combining that with single quotes, which inactivates interpolation, you would not need to escape.

```
ascii_art = <<'SOME_SEQUENCE_THAT_DOES_NOT_APPEAR_IN_THE_ASCII_ART'
                                      .....'',;;::cccllllllllllllcccc:::;;,,,''...'',,'..
                            ..';cldkO00KXNNNNXXXKK000OOkkkkkxxxxxddoooddddddxxxxkkkkOO0XXKx:.
                      .':ok0KXXXNXK0kxolc:;;,,,,,,,,,,,;;,,,''''''',,''..              .'lOXKd'
                 .,lx00Oxl:,'............''''''...................    ...,;;'.             .oKXd.
              .ckKKkc'...'',:::;,'.........'',;;::::;,'..........'',;;;,'.. .';;'.           'kNKc.
           .:kXXk:.    ..       ..................          .............,:c:'...;:'.         .dNNx.
          :0NKd,          .....''',,,,''..               ',...........',,,'',,::,...,,.        .dNNx.
         .xXd.         .:;'..         ..,'             .;,.               ...,,'';;'. ...       .oNNo
         .0K.         .;.              ;'              ';                      .'...'.           .oXX:
        .oNO.         .                 ,.              .     ..',::ccc:;,..     ..                lXX:
       .dNX:               ......       ;.                'cxOKK0OXWWWWWWWNX0kc.                    :KXd.
     .l0N0;             ;d0KKKKKXK0ko:...              .l0X0xc,...lXWWWWWWWWKO0Kx'                   ,ONKo.
   .lKNKl...'......'. .dXWN0kkk0NWWWWWN0o.            :KN0;.  .,cokXWWNNNNWNKkxONK: .,:c:.      .';;;;:lk0XXx;
  :KN0l';ll:'.         .,:lodxxkO00KXNWWWX000k.       oXNx;:okKX0kdl:::;'',;coxkkd, ...'. ...'''.......',:lxKO:.
 oNNk,;c,'',.                      ...;xNNOc,.         ,d0X0xc,.     .dOd,           ..;dOKXK00000Ox:.   ..''dKO,
'KW0,:,.,:..,oxkkkdl;'.                'KK'              ..           .dXX0o:'....,:oOXNN0d;.'. ..,lOKd.   .. ;KXl.
;XNd,;  ;. l00kxoooxKXKx:..ld:         ;KK'                             .:dkO000000Okxl;.   c0;      :KK;   .  ;XXc
'XXdc.  :. ..    '' 'kNNNKKKk,      .,dKNO.                                   ....       .'c0NO'      :X0.  ,.  xN0.
.kNOc'  ,.      .00. ..''...      .l0X0d;.             'dOkxo;...                    .;okKXK0KNXx;.   .0X:  ,.  lNX'
 ,KKdl  .c,    .dNK,            .;xXWKc.                .;:coOXO,,'.......       .,lx0XXOo;...oNWNXKk:.'KX;  '   dNX.
  :XXkc'....  .dNWXl        .';l0NXNKl.          ,lxkkkxo' .cK0.          ..;lx0XNX0xc.     ,0Nx'.','.kXo  .,  ,KNx.
   cXXd,,;:, .oXWNNKo'    .'..  .'.'dKk;        .cooollox;.xXXl     ..,cdOKXXX00NXc.      'oKWK'     ;k:  .l. ,0Nk.
    cXNx.  . ,KWX0NNNXOl'.           .o0Ooldk;            .:c;.':lxOKKK0xo:,.. ;XX:   .,lOXWWXd.      . .':,.lKXd.
     lXNo    cXWWWXooNWNXKko;'..       .lk0x;       ...,:ldk0KXNNOo:,..       ,OWNOxO0KXXNWNO,        ....'l0Xk,
     .dNK.   oNWWNo.cXK;;oOXNNXK0kxdolllllooooddxk00KKKK0kdoc:c0No        .'ckXWWWNXkc,;kNKl.          .,kXXk,
      'KXc  .dNWWX;.xNk.  .kNO::lodxkOXWN0OkxdlcxNKl,..        oN0'..,:ox0XNWWNNWXo.  ,ONO'           .o0Xk;
      .ONo    oNWWN0xXWK, .oNKc       .ONx.      ;X0.          .:XNKKNNWWWWNKkl;kNk. .cKXo.           .ON0;
      .xNd   cNWWWWWWWWKOkKNXxl:,'...;0Xo'.....'lXK;...',:lxk0KNWWWWNNKOd:..   lXKclON0:            .xNk.
      .dXd   ;XWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWNNNNNWWNNNNNNNNNWWNNNNNNWWWWWNXKNNk;..        .dNWWXd.             cXO.
      .xXo   .ONWNWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWNNK0ko:'..OXo          'l0NXx,              :KK,
      .OXc    :XNk0NWXKNWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWNNNX00NNx:'..       lXKc.     'lONN0l.              .oXK:
      .KX;    .dNKoON0;lXNkcld0NXo::cd0NNO:;,,'.. .0Xc            lXXo..'l0NNKd,.              .c0Nk,
      :XK.     .xNX0NKc.cXXl  ;KXl    .dN0.       .0No            .xNXOKNXOo,.               .l0Xk;.
     .dXk.      .lKWN0d::OWK;  lXXc    .OX:       .ONx.     . .,cdk0XNXOd;.   .'''....;c:'..;xKXx,
     .0No         .:dOKNNNWNKOxkXWXo:,,;ONk;,,,,,;c0NXOxxkO0XXNXKOdc,.  ..;::,...;lol;..:xKXOl.
     ,XX:             ..';cldxkOO0KKKXXXXXXXXXXKKKKK00Okxdol:;'..   .';::,..':llc,..'lkKXkc.
     :NX'    .     ''            ..................             .,;:;,',;ccc;'..'lkKX0d;.
     lNK.   .;      ,lc,.         ................        ..,,;;;;;;:::,....,lkKX0d:.
    .oN0.    .'.      .;ccc;,'....              ....'',;;;;;;;;;;'..   .;oOXX0d:.
    .dN0.      .;;,..       ....                ..''''''''....     .:dOKKko;.
     lNK'         ..,;::;;,'.........................           .;d0X0kc'.
     .xXO'                                                 .;oOK0x:.
      .cKKo.                                    .,:oxkkkxk0K0xc'.
        .oKKkc,.                         .';cok0XNNNX0Oxoc,.
          .;d0XX0kdlc:;,,,',,,;;:clodkO0KK0Okdl:,'..
              .,coxO0KXXXXXXXKK0OOxdoc:,..

                    ...
SOME_SEQUENCE_THAT_DOES_NOT_APPEAR_IN_THE_ASCII_ART
```

Comment: Heredoc also interpolates strings, so if `#{...}` happens to be included in the string (for which the OP hints there is a non-zero probability), you have Trouble; it's not enough to just pick out an unlikely terminator.

Comment: I was lazy to write about that. I fixed it.